# MLE fit for beta distribution given vector of rates?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, beta-distribution

Say that I have a vector of success rates, which are each ratios bound by [0,1]. I know how to get a normal approximation of this data; however, I'm interested in getting the MLE fit for Beta(a,b) which best described this distribution of rates.

I'm well aware of the Beta-Binomial Bayesian model. However, I do not have observed outcomes {0,1}, just the aggregated rates per individual.

What is the MLE formula or best way to infer the (a,b) parameters which describe the Beta distribution that best fits my distribution of rates?

Comment: Wikipedia has an extensive discussion on finding an [MLE estimator for the Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Maximum_likelihood) with references, saying it does "not have a general closed form solution for arbitrary values of the shape parameters".

Comment: Wikipedia does give an expression for a [method of moments estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Method_of_moments) using the sample mean $\bar x$ and sample variance $s^2$: $\hat \alpha=\bar x\left(\frac{\bar x (1-\bar x)}{s^2}-1\right)$ and $\hat \beta=(1-\bar x)\left(\frac{\bar x (1-\bar x)}{s^2}-1\right)$, at least when $s^2<\bar x (1-\bar x)$ so the estimates are non-negative.

Comment: I’m finding that in practice, grid search is good enough- there’s only two parameters to fit